# App doesn't respond for camera permission

Tags: android, surfaceview

This is a part of QR Code scanner app. In the very beginning of the app it asks for camera permission, when i click to allow, app doesn't respond. but from second time, app works correctly. I think the error may be in checking permission. Please help me to find the mistake.

```
surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new
                            String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246376/7360848 and if it solves the problem, mark it as the accepted answer please :)

Comment: @TouhidulIslam , i'm not getting you. What should i do for my code?

Comment: check my answer, you have to add `onRequestPermissionsResult ` callback